# Catharsis in Medea

Tags: greek-language, euripides, medea

Catharsis is defined by Aristotle as a pure release of supressed emotions. It generally occurs at the end of the play or at the resolution, when the audience undergoes a powerful experience of a range of emotions that include fear and pity.

Going through Medea, can it be argued that lines 222 to 284 consists of cathartic elements? Or is it catharsis?

I believe that in general Greek theatre structure, the catharsis comes at the climax of the play. But this speech by Medea is very emotionally engaging and is really emotionally intense.

These are the lines:

> Women of Corinth, here I am, as you wish and not as you might think, uncaring.
> All of us
> know women who no matter the occasion
> remain decorous, or because they stay at home
> are thought to be cold and implacable,
> indifferent to their neighbors’ needs.
> All of us judge by sight and not by knowledge.
> Because I’m an outsider I know this better than most,
> and have worked hard to fit in, but not, like some, I hope,
> in a prideful or aggressive way—
> even so I’m a target of suspicion,
> especially since Jason, yes, my faithless husband,
> tore out the threads I’d stitched to hold
> our life together. So quickly and suddenly
> was it done, I wasn’t given time to console
> myself or build alliances with friends.
> A brutal man whom I once loved has smashed me
> in the face so hard I wear the face of death.
> What other creatures are bred so exquisitely
> and purposefully for mistreatment as women are?
> Think of how we buy ourselves husbands,
> power and alliances for them, slavery
> and conquest over us. Bad enough
> to have no choice in servitude—
> but to pay for it and then celebrate
> a wedding feast adds salt to the wound.
> Try refusing the arrangement, or later
> petition for divorce—the first is impossible while the second is like admitting
> you’re a whore.
> And who ever warned us of a husband’s rough hands,
> breath aflame on our neck, or the inscrutable
> customs of his house?
> Some of you will say, “It’s not
> that bad”; and with work can learn the rules
> and maybe find a meager happiness.
> But as hard as we try to do the pleasing thing,
> it usually leads to resentment, complaints about our moods.
> That’s why when they seek out friends
> for entertainment, death looks so good to us,
> much better than our husbands who think
> we adore only them, grateful that they,
> not us, go off to war. But they’re wrong!
> deluded by soldier fantasies.
> If they like pain and danger let them take
> a turn at bearing children and for every birth
> I’ll fight three wars.
> But I’ve been talking as if our lives
> are the same. They’re not. You are Corinthians
> with ancestral homes, childhood friends,
> while I, stripped of that already,
> am now even more exposed by Jason’s cruelties.
> Remember how I came here, a war bride,
> plundered from my country, an orphan?
> Now who’s obligated to shelter me? Not you,
> I know. As you watch my plans for justice unfold,
> keep them secret, that’s all I ask. I’ve never felt
> this threatened nor fearless: men win their battles
> on the field but women are ruthless when the bed
> becomes the battleground. We’ve lain
> in our own blood before . . . and have survived.
>
> [[translation by Michael Collier and Georgia Machemer]](http://library.lol/main/5D0A8706D8836A7CD14FF284407CA1CC)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. What do you mean by *catharsis* or *has cathartic elements*? Please [clarify your question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/25802/edit) by adding details; as it stands, it's unclear what you're asking and any answers are likely to be opinion-based. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but while Aristotle's definition provides useful context, it's still unclear what you're asking: is it whether this speech brings out "a pure release of suppressed emotions" in the audience? That still seems opinion-based: *this speech seems pretty darn cathartic to me, do you agree?* (It doesn't help that you've not explained what you find cathartic about the speech.) 

Perhaps you could ask whether there is any scholarly consensus about where the catharsis occurs in *Medea*, and what scholars have had to say about this speech vis-à-vis catharsis?